# display textbox due selected option, and add new divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to have a robust solution that will show a dropdown menu,

```
<select id="sel">
<option value="Type 1">Type 1</option>
<option value="Type 2">Type 2</option>
</select>
```

after user selects an option, he should see related textboxes. (i know a solution and it works).

but, i need a button at the bottom that when clicked, user must see dropdown menu, select whichever option and see related textboxes and so on..

Any help is greatly (much and much more) appreciated..

jquery code

```
$(function() {
    //This hides all initial textboxes
    $('label').hide();
    $('#sel').change(function() {
        //This saves some time by caching the jquery value
        var val = $(this).val();
        //this hides any boxes that the previous selection might have left open
        $('label').hide();
        //This just opens the ones we want based off the selection
        switch (val){
            case 'option1':
            case 'option4':
            case 'other':
                $('#label1').show();
                break;
            case 'option2':
                $('#label1').show();
                $('#label2').show();
                $('#label3').show();
                break;
            case 'option3':
                $('#label1').show();
                $('#label2').show();
                break;        }
    });
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.Dropdown menu is to be created dynamically or you just want to show it after user click ??

Comment: dropdown menu will show dynamically and after selection, related textboxes dynamically have to created.

Comment: see my answer below i think that's all you need !!

Comment: hi harry,thank you for your effort. but that is not what  i am seeking. your code is only for one option, i mean after option1 is selected from dropdown box, it shows the textbox, that is OK. but i after that input, i have to add the very same dropdown menu and, after user selects option, NEW textbox should display.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:  [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8Vtu/5/)

Put the below code in `head section`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

$('#discountselection').hide();
$('#Yes').click(function() {
$('#discountselection').show();
$('#discountselection').removeAttr('disabled');
});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
       $(function() {
 //This hides all initial textboxes
  $('label').hide();
 $('#discountselection').change(function() {
    //This saves some time by caching the jquery value
    var val = $(this).val();
    //this hides any boxes that the previous selection might have left open
    $('label').hide();
    //This just opens the ones we want based off the selection
    switch (val){
        case 'option1':
        case 'option4':
        case 'other':
            $('#label1').show();
            break;
        case 'option2':
            $('#label2').show();

            break;
        case 'option3':
            $('#label3').show();

            break;        }
});
//I'm not really sure why these are here
$("input")
.focus(function () {
    $(this).next("span").fadeIn(1000);
})
.blur(function () {
     $(this).next("span").fadeOut(1000);
});
});

    </script>
```

Put the below code in your `body section`

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">

   <select class="purple" name="discountselection" id="discountselection" disabled>

     <option value="_">- select -</option>
     <option value="option1">put your data here</option>
        <option value="option2">put your data here</option>
        <option value="option3">put your data here</option>
    </select>        
          <br />  <br />        
                <input name="discount" type="button" id="Yes" value="click here to show drop down" />
                  <label id="label1" for="option1">
    //  1st text box
        <input type="text" id="option1" />
    </label>
    <label id="label2" for="option2">

      //2nd text box
        <input type="text" id="option2"/>
    </label>
    <label id="label3" for="option3">
       //3rd text box
        <input type="text" id="option3" />
    </label>

    </td>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

Hope It helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/Hz9vF/